# Assign JavaScript highlighting to [office-js] tag

Tags: feature-request, tags, syntax-highlighting

The [office-js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/office-js) tag is used for questions addressing Office Web Add-in's JavaScript library.

Since the sample code in these questions is universally JavaScript, it would be helpful to have the [office-js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/office-js) tag automatically assign `lang-js` for syntax highlighting.

Comment: Does that same formatting also apply to the typescript, angular and other variants used with the APIs?

Comment: Yes. Prettify considers `javascript`, `js`, `ts`, and `typescript` synonyms. Angular falls under TypeScript as well.